# How can I Search for Which of my Questions a Specific User has Answered?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, search, display-names

How can I search for which of my questions user 13 has answered?

None of these work:

- "user:me user:13"
- "user:me thirteen" (where *thirteen* is the user's name)
- "inquestion:me user:13"

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @yellowantphil I guess if there's not a way to do it with regular search I'll have to go figure out SEDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/571531?AnswererId=15416&AskerId=2642059) is a SEDE query that lists a specific user's answers to a specific user's questions:

```sql
select a.Id as [Post Link], a.CreationDate,
    case when p.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id then N'✓' else '' end as Accepted,
    a.Score as [Answer Score]
from Posts a
inner join Posts p on a.ParentId = p.Id
where a.OwnerUserId = ##AnswererId##
    and p.OwnerUserId = ##AskerId##
order by a.CreationDate desc
```

The results are updated every Sunday at 3:00 UTC.

Comment: Well this is pretty magical. I can't remember any database stuff, is there a way to add the check for whether I accepted the user's answer?

Comment: Looks amazing, I'll accept on Monday if I can't get any answers on how to do it with just regular search.

Answer (score 4):

With a bit of Stack Snippet magic and the use of the Stack API you can search in live data on your questions and their answers:

```js
(function () {
  // what we are calling
  var api = {
    url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/',
    endpoint: 'users/{0}/questions',
    params: { 
      site: 'stackoverflow',
      pagesize: 100,
      order: 'desc',
      sort: 'activity',
      Filter: '!6hYwaMGTMGHoxHfxsMZeS7MZ-zdSfzKByj6w*OnEd1W_ll',
      key: 'JBN9WXWxwrcnAj7WEEytmQ(('
      }
    },
    userid = 4342498;
    
  // glue both url and query string to one
  function createUrl(ap) {
    var ep = ap.url + ap.endpoint +'?',
     nv = [];
    $.each(ap.params, function (k,v) {
       nv.push(k + '=' + v);
    });
    console.log(ep + nv.join('&'));
    return ep + nv.join('&');
  }
 
  // add an answer to the final result
  function addResult(a) {
    var list = $('#Q');
    list.append(
            $('<div></div>').append(
            $('<a></a>')
              .attr('href', a.link)
              .attr('title', a.owner.display_name)
              .html(a.title)
            ));
  }
  
  // process each answer in the answer array
  function handleAnswers(answers) {
    var i, a;
    for(i = 0; i < answers.length; i = i + 1) {
      a = answers[i];
      // is this answer owned by the correct user?
      if (a.owner && a.owner.user_id === userid) {
        addResult(a);
      }
    }
  }
  
  // handle all question in the iteme array
  function handleItems(items) {
    var i, q;
    for(i = 0; i < items.length; i = i +1) {
          q = items[i];
          // don't bother handling if no answers
          if (q.answer_count>0) {
            handleAnswers(q.answers);       
          }
      }
  }
  
  // load a page of for questions of the owner
  function load(page) {
    api.params.page = page;
    $('#load').hide();
    $.get(createUrl(api), function (data) {
      var backoff = data.backoff || 0;
      
      handleItems(data.items);
      
      if (data.has_more) {
        // make sure to honor the backoff
        // or risk being IP banned
        window.setTimeout( function () {
              load(page +1);
            }, 
           backoff * 1000);  
      } else {
           // done
      }
    });
  }

  // bind the start to the button
  $('#go').on('click', function() {
    // owner questions
    api.endpoint = api.endpoint.replace('{0}', $('#ownid').val());
    // answer owner
    userid = parseInt($('#userid').val(),10); 
    // start at page 1
    load(1);
  });
  
}());
```

```css
label {display: inline-block; width: 150px; }
div { padding: 2px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error" style="display:none">
</div>
<h2>Find answers from a specific user</h2>
<div>
  <label for="ownid">My own user id:</label> 
  <input id="ownid" type='text' value='2642059' />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="userid">User Id on answers:</label> 
  <input id="userid" type='text' value='4342498' />
</div>
<div>
  <button id='go'>Search</button>
</div>
<div id="Q">
  
</div>
<div id="load" style="display:none">
 Click to load more ...
</div>
```

What I'm basically doing here is to fetch [/users/{id}/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=2642059&filter=!6hYwaMGTMGHoxHfxsMZeS7MZ-zdSfzKByj6w*OnEd1W_ll&site=stackoverflow&run=true) from the Stack API. I then iterate over the items that contain [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) types. Due to the [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) I applied the answers for the question are also returned. In each [answer](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer) I compare the user_id of the [owner](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/shallow-user) with the given value in the search form. When matched  the result is added to the result in the HTML DOM.

Comment: Amazing. The thing I'm not understanding is where did the `Filter` and `key` values come from?

Comment: @JonathanMee A filter can be build on each [endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users) under the **default** filter pop-up (at the right of the query form). That gives a value when saved and can then be copied. The key is obtained if you [register an app](http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) at Stack Apps. Once registered  you can share that key so users of *the app* get higher API quota. And when you abuse it, I get the complaints from SE DevOps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. I wish that I could accept both you and yellowantphil's answers this has been very enlightening for me in defining the powerful search functionality available to us.

Answer (score 1):

[yellowantphil's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337446/2642059) really answered my question. But I had also asked if I could filter by only accepted answers. I added another `join` to yellowantphil's answer to solve this, and I thought it might be helpful to future readers, so I figured I'd post it here:

```
select a.Id as [Post Link], a.CreationDate
from Posts a
join Posts p on a.ParentId = p.Id
join Posts v on v.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
where a.OwnerUserId = ##AnswererId##
and p.OwnerUserId = ##AskerId##
order by a.CreationDate desc
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/573519)