# How can I search for all questions sorted from newest to oldest that have answers for [swagger]?

Tags: support, tags, search

I'm trying to learn about Swagger and tried a few things and I'm wondering what are all of the questions that other users have asked and had answered with regards to swagger.

So there are two tags [swagger] and [swagger-ui] that I want to search (on either of the tags), but if I can only do one at a time, that is OK as well.

After I have this, I might want to also include that one of the answers to the question must have at least N upvotes (start with 10), as these questions are more likely to have been common questions.

### Things I've tried:

- In normal SO search I've used the search **[swagger] OR [swagger-ui]**.  This solution does find questions that have been tagged with swagger or swagger-ui but includes too many questions without answers.  I'm trying to quickly scan for all the answers to questions perhaps this is my cheat for a FAQ on swagger.
- I just learned about the data explorer feature, but have never used it.  I found a link to this URL [How can I Search for Which of my Questions a Specific User has Answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337444/how-can-i-search-for-which-of-my-questions-a-specific-user-has-answered) that used [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/571531/find-a-specific-users-answers-to-a-specific-users-questions?AnswererId=15416&AskerId=2642059), so I might need to have query to get what I'm looking for.  *I'll start looking at the query model to see if I can figure it out.*

Thanks, in advance, for any help.

Comment: Just found https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial to learn about queries

Comment: Using SEDE for this sounds like overcomplicating a very simply task. How about you look at range operators on [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) first?

Comment: Add `answers:1..` to your search to apply a range (1 or more).

Comment: @PatS the answers below refer to use of advanced search options, which you can build with a UI. Userscript: https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're interested in questions with an accepted or positively scored answer use the `isanswered:1` search option.

You can then combine this with your tags:

> [`[swagger] or [swagger-ui] isanswered:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bswagger%5d%20or%20%5bswagger-ui%5d%20isanswered%3a1&mixed=0)

to get the questions you're looking for.

Alternatively you can use a wildcard, for example `[swagger*]` to get all tags that start with *swagger*. Find more options in the [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) help page.

You can't upfront indicate how you want the result to be sorted but once the result is shown, you can click on one of the sort tabs (relevance, neewest, activity, votes). The results are always in descending order. Clicking any of the sort tabs adds the `tab` parameter to the url in the address bar:

> [image: sorted on newest is shown in URL]

You can add that url to the favorites of your browser to have this search and sort preference stored for future use.

If you would rather keep those settings on the site you might want to keep on eye on the feature [Custom question lists is available for testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing) that will add over time more options to select, sort and save your question 'filters'. To get a glimpse of what might become possible again see the now abandoned feature [new navagiation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate)

Comment: I like your answer best but as Mr Lister pointed out, his answer includes score:10 which was part of my question.   In the spirit of being fair, I selected his answer, but as I said in my comment to him, his answer doesn't address the sorting where your answer does.  So if you could add score to your answer, I think your answer is best for the community because it not only answers the question but provides dialog which helps enrich the users understanding.

Comment: @PatS I can't add score as that would be only the score for a question not for answers. You can only use SEDE or the stack api if you want to search based on questions and on properties of the answers of those questions.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize that.  Thanks for stating this.

Answer (score 6):

The search function offers a series of [advanced options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), including requiring that posts have a certain number of answers with

```
answers:1
```

or have a range of answer counts:

```
answers:1..10
```

where either end can be omitted. So to search for posts with 1 or more answers, use:

```
answers:1..
```

The results page then lets you sort by ‘newest’ (as well as by ‘active’,’votes’ and ‘relevance’).

There is no option to sort matching questions by the score of any of the associated answers however. That’d require a SEDE query.

Comment: thanks for including the link to advanced options.  That helped me understand what advanced options means.

Answer (score 3):

Some more additions to the existing posts...

1. To search for all tags starting with "swagger", search for `[swagger*]` (with an asterisk). That way, you'll get [swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swagger), [swagger-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swagger-ui) and a dozen others you may be interested in.
2. As others have mentioned, there is no "advanced search" option for sorting by newest first, although you can click on the "Newest" tab after hitting Search.
   What they have not pointed out though, is that clicking Newest results in a new URL

   > https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[swagger*]%20answers%3a1

   which you can bookmark, and then next time you can just invoke the bookmark rather than do all this over and over every time.

Answer (score 2):

Overall I suggest the `Newest` tab and:

```
[swagger] or [swagger-ui] score:10 is:a
```

Then click each result individually (~200) to reach the Q for the thread.

Comment: What does _Then click each result individually (~200) to reach the Q for the thread_ mean?

Comment: in my case, I wanted to also see the question so is:answer wasn't desired, but it is good to know about. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @PatS This answer shows how to get those answers with a score of 10 or higher, which is what you wanted. And clicking on those links also reveals the questions!